# Office cloud storage partner program registration

Tags: ms-office, ms-wopi

I am traying to make a registration for Office cloud storage partner program

From this link [Office cloud storage partner program registration](https://dev.office.com/programs/officecloudstoragepartnerprogram#collapse1)

I get this error "Error: Something went wrong while submitting the form."

When i use the form on this page [Office Cloud Storage Partner Program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cloud-storage-partner-program)

The form is submitted. But i get no receipt or any other response

Any suggestion for completing a registration

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to MS forums / MS support. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other-mso_win10-mso_online/office-cloud-storage-partner-program-is-not/db3208a8-3cbe-4b6a-a1c4-b27126a98f9d

Comment: Thread is locked, seams dead and there are no solution

Comment: I suggest you open a new thread. Or you can try [Dev Center](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?searchTerm=Is%20registration%20with%20Office%20365%20-%20Cloud%20Storage%20Partner%20Program%20is%20necessary%20to%20test%20integration%20of%20host%20application%20using%20WOPI%20with%20Office%20Online).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got reponse from Microsoft one week after sign up. Signede a NDA and now i am up and have now joined the program